# Order condition in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have two tables and I am joinning them using linq query

TableA with columns ID and Name

TableB with columns ID, TableAID and Order

TableB's column TableAID is a link between TableA and TableB. Please note that TableB my contain rows that do not exist in TableA

My data is as under

```
TableA
ID   Name
1    One
2    Two
3    Three

TableB
ID  TableAID   Order
1   1          2
2   2          1
3   4          1
4   5          1
```

In my linq query I want to select all rows from TableB with matching ID in TableA but the list should contain Name from TableA in the order of TableB. So my data should be

```
Two
One
```

Please help in building the linq statement

I have tried as below, but dont know where to put the order

```
 var MyList = TableA.Where(x => TableB.Any(y => y.TableAID == x.ID))
                         .ToList();
```

Comment: Have you tried something? Can you post your linq code?

Comment: Do you use O-RM (Do you have mapping from tables to classes)? If yes - what framework you use for this?

Comment: Sounds like you want an inner join, what have you tried?

Comment: Problem is that I loose the Order in TableA as I want to use the name. I am using entity framework but my code is complicated so given a simple example. I have added my simple linq in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your query will be like as given below example,

```
var data = (from a in context.TableA
           from b in context.TableB
           where a.ID == b.TableAID
           select new 
           {
               a.Name,
               b.Order
           }).Distinct().OrderByDescending(x => x.Order).ToList();
foreach(var item in data)
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can rewrite @M. Nasser Javaid answer in:

```
context.TableA.Join(context.TableB, a => a.ID, b => b.TableAID, 
    (a, b) => new {a.Name, b.Order}).Distinct()
.OrderByDescending(x => x.Order)
.Select(x => x.Name).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

```
var listresult = (from b1 in TableA
                          join a1 in TableB on b1.ID equals a1.TableAID
                          select new
                          {
                              b1.Name,
                              a1.Order
                          }).ToList().OrderByDescending(x=>x.Order);

        var final = (from m in listresult
                     select m.Name).ToList();
```